# EF does not recognize new Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

Last week I created my models for this project, but needed to update them this week. First my "Person" class only had a "Name" property and now it has a "Firstname" and a "Lastname" property. Now I get an exception about the "Name" property, which doesn't even exist anymore.

The DB is not being created either, which is most likely a subsequent error.

**Class Person**

```
abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Class Student**

```
class Student : Person
{
    public School School { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}
```

**Trying to add a Student**

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDbContext())
        {
            ctx.Persons.Add(new Student() {Firstname="Test" });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**DBContext**

```
class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolDbContext() : base("SchoolDB")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AArticle> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<APublisher> APublishers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

}
```

**The Exception**

*System.InvalidOperationException: "The property 'Name' is not a String or Byte array. Length can only be configured for String and Byte array properties."*

I tried cleaning the solution, restarting VS, rebuilding and recleaning... Cannot drop the DB as no DB is created.

How do I inform the compiler that the "Name" property does not exist anymore, as he does not get it himself?

Comment: Do tou have any migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your database with your code by so-called migrations: 
- ef core: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/
- ef 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/